# New TFrame and TDataModule crashing Delphi IDE

Tags: delphi, stack-overflow, frames, delphi-2006, datamodule

Here is the problem I've met:

Working in BDS 2006 IDE, my older computer gone, new ( i7 mount ) has been built and it has Windows 7 Ult OS 64bit, where 2006 was installed and QuickReports Pro as well as eDocEngine, FIB+, TMS, LMD, ZEOS & DB Comparer Component Packs - I use them in my products.

On computer I have Office 2010 installed as well, by default in 32bit version and Adobe CS6. That's it.

After installation I tried few times reinstall RAD 2009 and anyway, always the same problem, to simplify it is 100% reproducable like that:

- Create new Delphi VCL Forms application ;
- Click File / New / Other and goto, say, "Delphi files" and select `Frame` or `DataModule`. When new file is created, all the time we have message:

**"Stack overflow - save your work and restart Delphi for Microsoft Windows"**

After that IDE set in bad state and next F12 ( show VCL designer) closes Delphi with General Error.

Any idea what happens?

As I said, I tried few time uninstall - install 2006, start in any personality, use / do not use any of the updates or IDE fixes from Andy's site, nothing helps.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cause for this kind of behavior is probably some 3rd party components and/or IDE experts (IDE add-ons installed by some component suites). If you can reproduce this on a clean Delphi installation (without installing any 3rd party components), then the only thing I can recommend is first updating your Windows, all of your drivers and finally Delphi itself and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try running a second instance of the IDE in the debugger.

1. Create an empty dll or package project.
2. Open Run > Parameters
3. Set the host application to $(BDS)\bin\BDS.exe

Then just hit <kbd>F9</kbd> to run the second instance of the IDE in the debugger. After that just follow the steps to reproduce the problem and wait for the exception. If all goes well you'll get a complete call stack to step through.

Note: You may see various other exceptions occurring as the IDE loads. These are normal and can usually be ignored.

Also you didn't mention what version of Windows was on your old machine. If it was Windows XP Uwe could be right. XP was a little more lax on security by default than Vista or 7. The new default is to restrict write access to any folder under `Program Files`. If that turns out to be the problem you can adjust the write permissions for $(BDS) for whatever user account you use for development.

Comment: It was the same Windows Version. And the BDS folder is set to `C:\delphi\2006`

Comment: It's a great tip you did! 
In the result I got the not found erro in MDIAPP.ICO and SDIAPP.ICO at `C:\Users\Eduardo\Borland Studio Projects` folder. 
And the error I was getting with TFrame just stopped.

Answer (score 2):

Delete de PackageCache in Embarcadero registry entries. Its not a complete solution but worked for me.

Got that from here: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=118669 (last answer).

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).

Answer (score 0):

I have no BDS 2006 at hand, but is it possible that the default folder for new projects is located below the Program Files folder? In that case there might be no write access to that folder.

Comment: I usually create my projects on a dropbox folder so I thay can be safe from hardware fail and easy access from pc, notebook and smartphones. I haven't changed the projec default folder from `Users\Me\Borland Projects`, so my applications have the right permission. Thank you!